# How to Select ImageView ids from mutiple Imageviews with drag and drop functionality

Tags: java, android

I just started working on android and I'm relatively new to the technology. I made 3 horizontal scrolls with drag and drop functionality and I want to drag and drop them in a certain area while keeping count of failed and successful drops. So far I accomplished everything but the code is not that effective and the approach I believe is not the best one. I want to know about a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Part of my activity_main.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:onClick="onTouch">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a9"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a10"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src= "@drawable/a8"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int id;
    ImageView drag;
    LinearLayout drop;
    TextView text, success, fail;
    int total, failure, succ = 0, i;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        drag = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

        drag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(drag);
                v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });


        drop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total);
        success = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Success);
        fail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fail);

        drop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        {
                            succ = succ + 1;
                            return (true);
                        }

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        {
                            total = total + 1;
                            int failure = total - succ;
                            success.setText("Sucessful Drops :" + succ);
                            text.setText("Total Drops: " + total);
                            fail.setText("Failed Drops: " + failure);
                            return (true);

                        }

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code works for only first image view and I need a solution that enables all of them. I tried using ImageView array with for loop but that only returns the last ImageView. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an array for this but the main issue was that I was always getting the last image view no matter what I select. This issue was resolved by using 'final' keyword.

```
final ImageView drag = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
```

This resulted in me getting distinct image views on drag. All the responses are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but You have not entered proper description in question with Your wrong array implementation, I gave You proper solution for Your question, it was not possible to know how wrong was array implemented

Comment: And next thing if You had final variable then it would throw an exception with every try to assign it again.

Comment: I just used the 'final' keyword and it worked just fine before which I was always getting the last image view in any case. Not posting the wrong solution was my bad I'm sorry for that and yes I just tried your exact solution.

It works fine except for the fact that it always end up selecting the last image view similar to what my array used to do 'final' keyword resolved that issue.

Answer (score 2):

To not change fully Your implementation I would go to solution with method which get in parameter `id` of `imageView`.

```
void dragAndDropImage(String imageId){

  // get int id from String
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageId, "id", getPackageName());

  //here Your drag and drop functionality code
  ImageView drag = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

  //... rest of code

}
```

Use it:

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){

    //loop over every imageView ( from 1 to 10 )
    dragAndDropImage("b"+i);

}
```

Few more refactoring notes:

- `drop, text, success, fail` views should be stored in some class property to avoid doing findViewById every time
- drag `touchListener` should be some subClass of activity
- `onDragListener` should be also some subClass of activity

Comment: I actually tired that using an array it always returns the last image meaning no matter what I select it will drag the last Image View. I know this because I have the shadow effect in there and every time I drag its always the last image view regardless of what I'm selecting.

Comment: But You tried exactly that solution which I proposed?

Comment: "I tried using ImageView array with for loop but that only returns the last ImageView" It think You have done something wrong. Check my solution.

Comment: I think problem can be that You had drag as class property and every loop was overwriting it. It should be new instance every time like I showed in answer - ImageView drag = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Horizontal` `Recyclerview`

This link will help with vertical recyclerview  [Verticle Reclyclerview drag and drop](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.9kzitt7id)

And then do some modification in that like

set Layout manager horizontal in recylerview

```
 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

**LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL** for horizontal list with recylerview

You will get `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback` class form that demo
And modified method  `getMovementFlags` method like

```
 @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

            final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
            final int swipeFlags = 0;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);

    }
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

In you drag listener you can pass object type where you had pass the null.

```
drag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {

                PassObject object=new PassObject();
                 object.setId("id");
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(drag);
                v.startDrag(data, shadow, object, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And in Listener where you are implementing their you can get it.

drop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    {
                        //succ = succ + 1;
                        return (true);
                    }

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    {
            PassObject passObject = (PassObject) event.getLocalState();
                String id=passobject.getID();
                        return true;

                    }

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```